# Change time quant for SCHED_OTHER scheduler

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel

I checked in the man documentation the following stuff "SCHED_OTHER  the standard round-robin time-shring policy". Is it possible to change number of the time-quant for this scheduler? I guess that it could be useful for long-term jobs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SCHED_OTHER is the default linux schedule policy and follow a round-robin mechanism with the timeslice value depending on the "niceness" value of a process. When you start a process, by default it has a niceness 0 which implies a timeslice of 100ms.

Now there are two ways to change the timeslice.
1) You can change the niceness using the command *renice* (http://linux.die.net/man/8/renice).
2) You may change the default Linux timeslice, which is defined in the Linux kernel as RR_TIMESLICE in include/linux/sched/rt.h (default 100ms).